# How can I force the browser to print a PDF version of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Consider a static HTML page as `test.html`, and a printable version of the page has been stored in `test.pdf`. How can I guide browser to load and print `test.pdf` instead of `test.html` when visitors tell **their browser** to print?

If it's not possible how can I introduce a print button (using JavaScript) within the HTML page to do so?

Comment: You can do this via PHP. Not JS. http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm In JS, you've already sent the file headers, so you can't do exotic stuff like this.

Comment: 1. This will download the file, not print; 2. Even if loading the pdf, it will open it not print.

Comment: Oops I misread the question. One thing that may work (dunno) is loading the pdf in an iframe and calling  the iframe's print. But I'm not sure how much DOM is preserved.

Comment: I’m confused, are you using a print friendly CSS or a pre-made PDF file? because these are very different things.

Comment: @Ali, I've rolled back your edit. You cannot change a question entirely after answers have already been provided. Requesting a CSS solution to customize what's printed is totally different than opening a PDF when printing. Please create a new question if you have changed your requirements.

Comment: @JamesHill I do not want a CSS solution, I wanted to clarify the case. I said something like that but for reading a PDF file.

Comment: @Ali, Sorry for the confusion. I misunderstood. What you're asking for simply isn't possible. My solution is as close as you're going to get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot force the browser to print a different file than the user is requesting/viewing. That would be a security nightmare!

**Option 1 (JS (as requested) & HTML)**

I suggest creating a `printable version` link on your site that will direct the user to the .pdf (opening the PDF in a new window would be preferable).

```
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadPrintableVersion() {
        window.open("Test.pdf");
    }
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<span id="spanPrintableVersion" onclick="LoadPrintableVersion()">
    Printable Version
</span>
```

**Option 2 (pure html)**

```
<a href="test.pdf" target="_blank">Printable Version</a>
```

Comment: Why not just link to the PDF using an `<a>` tag? Then it will also work without JS.

Comment: @David, because the user specifically asked for JS and I was in my JS box :) I'll provide a pure html example (because your point is valid)!

Comment: Please explain how sending a different document to the printer is a "security nightmare"?

Comment: @Supuhstar, seriously? I could think of a million nefarious uses for this. The better question is, aside from CSS styling to make things more user-friendly when printed, why anyone **want** to print something other than what is on screen? If the user chooses to print what's on screen, they should know what is being printed.

Comment: @JamesHill here are just a few examples I can think of off the top of my head: A personal resume with a specially-formatted version to ensure it always prints on 1 page; Google Maps, where printing a search for directions prints step-by-step directions instead of what's on the screen; a Flash (or Silverlight or Canvas) only website, where a preview image has been created and should be printed, as the currently-displayed content isn't always immediately comprehensible

Comment: @JamesHill also, yes, seriously. How can one use a printer and a webpage to compromise another user's security remotely?

Answer (score 3):

You can’t hijack the print command in the browser, but you can hijack keyboard shortcuts (although I wouldn’t recommend it) so that when the user prints using `ctrl/cmd + p`, it redirects to a PDF (or does something else). This is a usability minefield though, you should probably just create a big link that says "Printable version" and link it to the PDF (or a version of the page that uses a print-friendly CSS).

Another good options is to simply define some rules for the `print` media type in your CSS file, then the browsers will apply those when the user prints, without any hacks or javascript at all.

But since you asked I created a small shortcut hijacking script for the print command. It‘s kind of tricky because of the mac command key, but something like:

```
var cmd = false;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

    if(detectMacCommand(e.which)) {
        cmd = true;
        return;
    }

    // now detect print (ctr/cmd + p)
    if ( e.which == 80 && ( e.ctrl || cmd ) ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('redirect to PDF');
    }

}).on('keyup', function(e) {

    if(detectMacCommand(e.which)) {
        cmd = false;
        return;
    }

});

function detectMacCommand(key) {
    return ( $.browser.mozilla && key == 224 ||
             $.browser.opera   && key == 17 ||
             $.browser.webkit  && ( key == 91 || key == 93 ));
}
​
```

That’s pretty cool, but don’t use it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way the W3C says you should:

```
<LINK REL="alternate" HREF="/path/to/PDFVersion.pdf" TYPE="application/pdf" MEDIA="print" TITLE="PDF version" />
```

Mind you, as far as I can tell, **no browser currently supports this**. Sorry.