# Can I print a .pdf document from a website when the user prints the page instead of the website styled with media css?

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, printing

I am working on a website that is essentially a database of video/audio presentations, each with an accompanying transcript, and we have a PDF version of each presentation's transcript already created and uploaded on the website for users to print, but not all users look for the "download PDF" button so they just hit "ctrl + p", which spits out a horrendously misaligned attempt to cram our page's css into a print document.  Is there anyway to just print out that PDF that we already have when someone hits the print command, so that the downloaded PDF and the printed webpage would appear identical?  Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhhh yes I was looking forever for something like that.  I knew I couldn't have been the first person to ask this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look into the wkhtmltopdf library - https://wkhtmltopdf.org

There are a number of wrappers for the library too, such as Snappy for Laravel (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

Update:  I have reread your question and understand what you are asking now.  Have you seen this thread? [How can I force the browser to print a PDF version of a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669270/how-can-i-force-the-browser-to-print-a-pdf-version-of-a-webpage)